# log4cplus does not show all messages

Tags: c++, linux, log4cplus

We are building a module that is part of a full embedded Linux operating systems. We are using log4cplus for diagnostics.

**log.properties** contains:

```
log4cplus.logger.CompanyGlue=TRACE, console
```

**cm_bind_helper.h** contains much more complicated than this. All of the **DBG_XXX** messages appear on the console.

```
#include "qobject.h"
#include "log4cplus/dbglog.h"
class bind_helper : public QObject
{
protected:
    const char *debugModuleName = "CompanyGlue";
    log4cplus::Logger debugModule { Logger::getInstance(debugModuleName) };

    bool set_value(CMPath path, PType &input)
    {
        auto old_value = CMRoot()->getValue(path);
        if (input != old_value) {
            DBG_DEBUG("Changing " << path << " to " << input);
        }
    }
}
```

**cm_bridge.cpp** contains much more code than this. However, none of the **DBG_XXX** messages appear on the console.

```
#include "cm_bridge.h"
#include "cm_bind_helpers.h"

struct CompanyContentModelBridge::detail_ : public bind_helper
{
    std::shared_ptr<company::device_base> base;

    detail_(QObject *parent)
        : bind_helper(parent)
    {
        configure_system_advanced_control();
    }
    void configure_system_advanced_control();
    std::string get_exported_file_size();
}

using detail_ = CompanyContentModelBridge::detail_;

void detail_::configure_system_advanced_control()
{
    base->add_get_only_entry<std::string>("SPDSZ", get_exported_file_size());
}

std::string detail_::get_exported_file_size()
{
    DBG_INFO("get exported file size");
    //diag("exported file size");
}
```

I have tried various ways to configure log4cplus in **cm_bridge.cpp**, including the same two lines in **cm_bind_helpers.h** and as follows. I also removed them assuming that inheritance would handle it. Nothing made the **DBG_XXX** messages appear.

```
DBG_IMPL_DEBUG_MODULE(CompanyGlue);
```

Eventually, I added this function to **cm_bind_helpers.h**. It worked when called from its own class but failed when called from get_exported_file_size() (with comment removed).

```
void diag(std::string_view what) {
    DBG_DEBUG("bind helper diag " << what);
}
```

I'm stumped. I do not know why messages are being suppressed from one file but not the other.

Comment: Have you debugged the code, just add a breakpoint in `detail_::get_exported_file_size` to see what happens

Comment: What version of log4cplus are you using?

Comment: What is `log4cplus/dbglog.h`? I can't see that in the log4cplus sources.

Comment: I cannot debug the code because a library is not found. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67727624/vscode-dedug-cannot-find-shared-library

Comment: I found that the function is called upon start-up and not when I send a command asking for it. That solves this question. find library=liblog4cplus.so.0